# How to tell binary form from ternary form?

Tags: theory, musical-forms

I know that binary form has 2 equal sections (AB) and ternary has 3 (ABA), but because my piece of ABA form music has 6 bars and can be divided into 3 equal sections, it means that the same total number of bars can be divided into 2.  So with the uploaded attachment, how am I able to determine it is not a binary tune?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Ah, vous dirai-je, Maman*? It's essentially ternary. The first 4-bar phrase starts and ends on the tonic; the repeated 2-bar phrases are pretty much elaborating the dominant; and the last 4-bar phrase performs a slightly varied reprise of the first. The very clear tonal scheme and the equally clear thematic divisions enforce this reading. The repetition of the middle two bars acts as a unitary idea, not as an ending of the first half/start of the second.

Comment: In the version Mozart uses in his variations, this is a rounded binary with written repeat signs around the two sections.

Comment: He had to impose repeats where there were none to achieve that, @AndrewCashner, which shows us how close rounded binary form is to small ternary form. Indeed, I've always considered rounded binary form that _doesn't_ move to the dominant before the first repeat to be a rondeau-like variation on simple ternary.